# MongoDB group performance in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

As a preface, I'm using Node.js with Mongo-db-native.

I'm also using GridFS to store images and each image has meta data, one of which is a Product Id.

I want to query all the the `fs.files` and return images that are associated to a specific product.

Here's how I am currently doing this:

```
this.collection.ensureIndex({
    product_id: 1,
}, function (err, edIndex) {
    self.collection.group(   ['group'] , {
        "product_id": ObjectID(product_id)
    } , {
        docs: []
    } , function (doc, prev) {
        prev.docs.push({
            width: doc.width,
            height: doc.height,
            _id: doc._id
        });
    } , true , function (err, results) { 
        if (err) {
            callback(err)
        } else {
            callback(null, results)
        } 
    });
});
```

I'm finding that this is extremely slow.  Does anyone have any suggestions as an alternative or how to increase the performance of this?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you posted the correct code?

Comment: ensureIndex() creates an index so there is no need to call it for each query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple query in Mongo shell syntax which will find all GridFS files with ProductId = 42 in its metadata.

```
db.fs.files.find({"metadata.ProductId": 42});
```

The returned documents will contain a filename which can be used with mongo-native's GridStore.

Comment: Well, there's a little more going on, I'm building a new array based on the sizes, but I guess i could do that outside of mongo, without using a group aggregate.

Comment: Map reduce, which lies behind mongo-native's group, is great for some types of problems. I find it overkill for something as simple as appending results to a new array.